# How To get Maximo 7.6.1 log in page after Installation

Tags: maximo

I am new to Maximo 7.6.1 installation. Have installed DB2, WAS 11.01 and Maximo 7.6.1 . All of them on the same personal laptop running Windows 10.

Installations successful (except for the final ear deployment). DB2 and WAS are successfully installed. On rebooting the laptop, I get following different logins db2admin,
maximo ,
maxdb76

My question is using which url I can access/ or get the login page of Maximo.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying this [url](http://hostname/maximo/ui/maximo.jsp) based on your setup.

You may need to specify a port after hostname (e.g. :9080) if one is configured and specifying localhost or your IP address (found by running ipconfig from the command line) can help rule out any issues with hostname.

Answer (score 0):

You said, "except for the final ear deployment" ... but it is that final EAR deployment that makes Maximo run when you start the app server you deploy it to. Once it is deployed and running, you should be able to access the Maximo login page by browsing to http://localhost:9080/maximo or https://localhost:9443/maximo.